# how can i use 'distinct' from my database

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

I have a query using active records.

```
function gettime($doctor_id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->distinct('date');
        $this->db->from('availability');
        $this->db->where('doctor_id',$doctor_id);      
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

I want to fetch distinct(date).

can anyone tell me my mistake where should i change?

Comment: Try this `$this->db->select('DISTINCT name');`

Comment: try $this->db->group_by('date');, in distinct no need to set column name.

Comment: Which language is that? It's not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
function gettime($doctor_id){
        $this->db->select('DISTINCT date');
        $this->db->from('availability');
        $this->db->where('doctor_id',$doctor_id);      
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function gettime($doctor_id){
        $this->db->select('DISTINCT date');
        $this->db->from('availability');
        $this->db->where('doctor_id',$doctor_id);  
        $this->db->group_by('date');    
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```